# No Bootable device found on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 18.04, partitioning, bios

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my system. But whenever I try to boot up the device I get no bootable device found error.
I tried to mess around in the bios (APTIO Bios Utility) and found out an option as ' Boot Option #1'. By default this is always set to P0 (The Hard Disk). The other value to which this option can be set is 'Disabled'. I changed it to disabled and it worked as my Ubuntu will boot up. But this isnt a proper solution to my problem because every time I want to start my system I have to manually set the value as Disabled. ( Another thing I have doubt is, why does disabling the hard drive gives me a proper boot? Technically, on disabling the hard drive should result in No Bootable media found error).

I have been trying out a numerous solutions online but nothing seems to work. Please help me out.

Comment: what is your hardware? sounds like the BIOS is at fault here. If your BIOS does not save boot order or other setting on each boot either the motherboard is an antique or it's broken. is it one of those with button cell battery? normally it should only affect onboard time not saved bios settings but it could be possible you need to replace that battery for the BIOS to save the settings. If there happens to be a newer version of your BIOS you absolutely MUST flash your motherboard. is the option "Secure Boot" on or off?

Comment: Thanks for the response....It has TPM 2.0 but I have kept it disabled. And it is not using UEFI. It is in legacy so no secure boot.

Comment: The hardware is ABB SSC600 Smart Substation Control and Protection.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! **;-)** I agree with @tatsu: BIOS boot error.  Contact the vendor.

Comment: ok....probably have to do that only.....thank you guys for the help.